# Euclidean space is an affine space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, affine-geometry

I know the fact that each Euclidean space is an affine space.But I was troubled by the definition of affine space.
see
[Vector Spaces versus Affine Spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2951824/vector-spaces-versus-affine-spaces?r=SearchResults)

The definition of an affine space consists a triple $(A,V,\phi)$.Take the Euclidean space $\Bbb R^2$ for example,what is the set $A$  and what is the vector space $V$?

Comment: Sorry, what is $\phi$ here? An affine isomorphism or an 'action' of the vector space by addition? In any case, take $A=V(=\Bbb R^2)$.

Comment: $\phi$ is the map$A\times A \to V$

Comment: Aha, that would correspond to subtraction, which can be turned around to an action $V\times A\to A$ as 'addition' (i.e. translation of elements of $A$ by vectors of $V$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a linear space $V$, the corresponding affine space is $(V, V, \phi)$ where $\phi(v, w) =w-v$ (or $v+w$, depending on your definition) is the canonical action.

Comment: If we define the map $\phi:V\times A\to A$,when we tall about the affine normed space V,the set $A$ is also $V$?I asked others,they told me that $A$ can be any set,I was quite confused!

Comment: Yes in general, $A$ can be any set, (no need to be a vector space), and $\phi$ puts an affine structure on it, so that we can 'translate' points of $A$ by vectors of $V$. A canonical example is $A=V+w$ with $V$ a subspace of some vector space $W$ and $w\in W$.